# Android pass firebase auth object to another activity to sign out

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

I login the user in Main Activity but I want to log out the user in another activity via a button. However, I can't pass the `FirebaseAuth` object to the other activity.

PutParcelable and PutSerializable won't work because I have no control over the class itself. The shared preference only accepts primitive types. Should I get a new instance in the new activity and logout the user in the new activity? Will the state of the user be preserved even I get a new instance?

here's the code

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are logged in!!!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);

                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }

            }
        };
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

FirebaseAuth is a singleton class, you can get instance of firebase auth anywhere from the app.

You just need to add

```
 mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
  // Firebase sign out
  mAuth.signOut();
```

Or simple way

`FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();`